# Unable to access Laravel public disk in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed a laravel app using AWS Elastic Beanstalk service. The application works as expected but failing to load picture files. On my local system everything works fine so I am wondering why pictures are not found on the ec2 instance.

The files are stored inside `storage/app/public` and a symbolic link was created to `public/storage` as recommend in [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk)

This is the code for displaying the photo

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('storage/images/photos/'.$photo->photo) }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

This works fine on local system

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/photos/rayda_concept_photos_639.jpeg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

But fails on AWS ec2

```
<img src="http://raydaconcept-env.tpttmzwdki.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/storage/images/photos/rayda_concept_photos_691.jpeg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

Here's the [live link](http://raydaconcept-env.tpttmzwdki.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/) to see this error live. Kindly help me fix this error.

Comment: Just for fun trying swapping http for https

Comment: @BradGoldsmith well I tried that from developer tools but still didin't display the pictures. Do you know how to make the site use https instead of http?

Comment: Look into Laravel Valet and using the secure command.